# AppConKit: Set a URL based on the currently configured URL

Tags: appconkit

In the AppConKit, you can give your users the option to configure a Servername, port and path in the Settings that this Apps connects to. Can I somehow access these configured settings in the Javascript code?
My use-case is that I have a logo image sitting on the server the app is connecting to, and would like to show this logo based on the server url.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes sense, but that's not a setting that is easily accessible (yet).

You can access the settings via the device switch:

```
var hostname;
var port;
var path;
if (vMobileController.device().isAndroid()) {
    hostname = vKVS.value("Weptun_Hostname");
    port = vKVS.value("Weptun_Port");
    path = vKVS.value("Weptun_URL_Path");
} else { 
    hostname = vKVS.value("server_url");
    port = vKVS.value("server_port");
    path = vKVS.value("server_endpoint");
}
if (hostname.substring(0,4)!="http") {
    hostname="http://"+hostname;
}
var vUrl = hostname+":"+port+"/"+path+"/images/Logo.png";
```

I talked with the developers tho, and it would make sense to access this via direct Javascript API. I'll see that it's added to the roadmap!